# unbind jQuery infinite scroll when used alongside pjax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I'm using a very simple jQuery infinite scroll to eliminate the need for numbered pagination but I'm coming across a small issue.

When I go to the page that uses the infinite scroll and it loads it, the infinite scroll will work as planned but when I then navigate away from that page using `pjax` it will still run on **all** other site pages as it's still a loaded function?

What can I do to basically tell the infinite scroll function to only run on the pages I want it to or somehow reset it when pjax changes the page?

Here's my code for the infinite scroll so far:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

        // Do scroll pagination, load content into #load-here ..
    }
}
```

This is how I want the scroll to function:

```
$("a:not(.no-dynamic)").pjax("#main");

$(document).on('pjax:end',   function() {
    if($("#load-here").length == 0) {
        $(window).off("scroll");
    }
    else
        $(window).on("scroll");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue. Fixed it by unbinding the scroll handler if a particular div (hidden pagination div) doesn't exists any more.

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($('#pagination').length == 0){
   $(window).unbind('scroll',<<scroll handler function>>);

        return;
}
  ......
}
```

Comment: How do you turn scroll back on though? for me once it's unbinded it doesn't work again until refreshed?

Comment: - Write a function - scrollHandler.  -Bind the scroll function to window scroll when $('#pagination') div exists & Unbind when it doesn't exists any more.   (with jquery ajax, can do this in ajaxComplete event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Instead of `$(window).scroll()`, do:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    // stuff
});
```

I've never used pjax, but according to the [docs](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events), there's an `end` callback you can use:

```
$(document)
    .on('pjax:end', function() {
        $(window).off('scroll');
    });
```

The idea is to unbind the "scroll" event from `window` every time a pjax request ends.

Comment: Ah I see, I've not used `.off()` before, that looks like what I need.

Comment: This works turning the scroll off, but then the scroll doesn't work on the next page at all, even with `$(window).on('scroll', function() { });` ?

Answer (score 0):

handle [window.onbeforeunload](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm) to unbind infinite scroll

Comment: I don't think `onbeforeunload` gets triggered with pjax. Could be wrong though...